# Javascript is not defining a variable loaded from SQL column and outputted using dojo

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, iis

I have the following ASP.NET, javascript code:

```
var decPts = <%=currentDec.Survey.User.DecPts %>;
var locn = <%=currentDec.Survey.User.Location %>;
function sDPts(dn) {
    return ((Math.round(dn * Math.pow(10, decPts)) / Math.pow(10,
            decPts)).toFixed(decPts));
}
function update(decNumber) {
    dojo.byId('debug1').innerHTML = "decPts = (" + decPts + ")";
    dojo.byId('debug2').innerHTML = "Location = (" + locn + ")";
}
```

```
<asp:content>
        <div id="debug1"></div>
        <div id="debug2"></div>

</content>
```

I get the following:

```
decPts = (2)               ---- correct
Location = (undefined)     ---- not correct
```

DecPts and Location are columns in a SQL database record.
DecPts is int and Location is string

If I rewrite the HTML as

```
<div id="debug1"></div></td>
<div id="debug2"><%=currentDec.Survey.User.Location %></div>
```

I get the correct answer, i.e.

```
decPts = (2)
US
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I assume `locn` is supposed to be a string? If so, then you need to encapsulate it with quotes. `var locn = '<%=...%>';` Either way, you should be careful for [reflected XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).

Comment: Yes. That fixed it. I assumed javascript variable would take on the type specified in the definition of the column. Anyway it works. Thanks !!

Comment: No, JavaScript and your asp.net run on completely different environments. (See [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)) The location is literally parsed into the JavaScript code and the JavaScript is then send to the user's browser and executed there. All relations to the database are gone there.

Comment: Of course. One thing I hadn't mentioned: one of the things I tried was String(<%=currentDec.Survey.User.Location %>). Shouldn't that have helped?

Comment: I don't know if that is some kind of asp.net function that adds the quotes for you (I haven't used asp.net in 10 years), but otherwise it wouldn't have made a difference. If you want to use a string literal in your JavaScript code, it needs to be encapsulated with quotes.

Comment: Try dojo.byId('debug2').innerHTML = "Location = (" + locn.ToString() + ")";

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I think the general question I have is why does
       dojo.byId('debug1').innerHTML = "decPts = (" + decPts + ")";
work when decPtr is a number but
    dojo.byId('debug2').innerHTML = "Location = (" + locn + ")";
fails when locn is a string? In the first case javascript is converting decPtr to
a string, i.e. string + num + string -> string but
fails with location, i.e string + string +string fails.